# Python pandas filtered crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, filter, crosstab

Working with the dataframe df:

```
Customer_ID | Transaction_ ID | Store_nr | Store_type | dollars 
ABC           1234              1          Retail       567
ABC           4567              2          Digital      893
ABC           6789              2          Digital      189
ABC           3456              4          Retail       908
XYZ           2345              3          Digital      893
XYZ           5678              1          Retail       792
XYZ           7890              2          Digital      145
```

I want to create a crosstab that counts customers **uniquely** between the Retail and digital Stores.

This is the output I am looking for:

```
                Digital Digital
       Store nr    2     3
Retail     1       2     1   
Retail     4       1     0
```

So you would read the above as, there were 2 people who shopped in store 1 and 2; there was one person who shopped in store 4 and 2 and one who shopped in 1 and 3. There were no people who shopped in 4 and 3.

I realize that I should use python's crosstab function http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.crosstab.html

But I don't know how to filter the vertical side for Store_type = Retail and the horizontal side for Store_type = Digital.

I was thinking of maybe using a pivot instead, but I hit the same problem.

Thank You!